# Pytest: capture logs for a specific

Tags: python, pytest

I use pytest as my automation framework. I want to capture all the emitted logs from a specific test and store it somewhere. How do I access logs after the test is finished? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**First things first - [RTFM](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html)**

Few things you can do right away:

- pass `-vvv` switch in the CLI
- redirect `stdout` to a file
- check out plugins like [pytest-html](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html)